# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm doing a simple login page for Visual Basic connected to an access database and I keep receiving this error when I run the project.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me resolve this.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmLogin

    Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Login.accdb")
    Dim objDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User", objConnection)

    Dim objCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objDA)
    Dim objDS As New DataSet()
    Public Username, Password As String
    Dim UserFound As Boolean

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Retrieve()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Username = txtUser.Text
        Password = txtPassword.Text

        For i As Integer = 1 To (objDS.Tables("User").Rows.Count)

            If CStr(objDS.Tables("User").Rows(i - 1).Item("Username")) =
           Username And
            CStr(objDS.Tables("User").Rows(i - 1).Item("Password")) = Password Then
                UserFound = True
                Me.Hide()
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the System!")
                frmStudents.Show()
                Exit For
            End If
            txtUser.Text = String.Empty
            txtPassword.Text = String.Empty
        Next
        If UserFound = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Access Denied")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Retrieve()
        objDS.Clear()
        objDA.FillSchema(objDS, SchemaType.Source, "User")
        objDA.Fill(objDS, "User")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error occurs in this line:

> objDA.FillSchema(objDS, SchemaType.Source, "User") "User" is
>   underlined in the error

This is further info on the error shown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Additional information: Conversion from
>   string "User" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Comment: Where do you get this error? Post the complete errror-message including stacktrace.

Comment: Put the relevant information in the post not in comments.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  And never store passwords as plain text - they should be salted and hashed

Comment: Okay, will change that. Sorry, first time using this!

Comment: Why are you calling `FillSchema` at all? The point of that method is the propagate schema from database to `DataTable` without data but you call `Fill` immediately after anyway. `Fill` will do what `FillSchema` does plus more, so calling both is pointless.

Comment: You really ought to turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties too.  It will flag certain issues at compile time instead of letting them slip to run time.  Turn it `On` in the IDE options as well, so it's `On` by default for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hauling down the entire users table just to verify a user get the count of records that match. Of course, in a real application, you would never store password as plain text.

```
Private Sub VerifyUser()
        Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Login.accdb")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Count(*) From Users Where [Username] = @Username and [Passwor] = @Password;", objConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Test
        objConnection.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        Dim message As String = ""
        If count > 0 Then
            message = "Welcome"
        Else
            message = "Sorry"
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(message)
    End Sub
```